# How to implement auto increment column value alphabetical?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tbl_login` and I want my column id to be auto increment and alphabetical also. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
ID      Name    Pass
101A    Mohan   1234
102B    Madan   4321
103C    Ram     12334
```

Comment: Show some samples..

Comment: That does not seem reasonable.  What is wrong with a numeric identity?

Comment: What should be the value after `126Z` ?

Comment: after 126Z next value is 127AA

Comment: That's a terrible design @ManishSingh. Share your aim to do this and we can propose something better maybe ?

Comment: Why you need to generate values like this ?

Comment: Simple answer: don't.... maybe an extra column with a calculated value calling a SQL function may do the trick but, as mentioned before, this is bad design.

Comment: `126Z` --> `127AA` whats the rule for going single or double `A`? Your first value was a single `A` (101A). Put me in the "This is a terrible idea" camp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Nice question.

i) This id can be generated upto how much digit ?like 10,000 or 1,00,000 or more

ii) You should throw little more example randomly start from 101 .specially throw few example from 4 digit and few from 5 digits.

iii)how you are going to implement it.Like will you insert single row or you will insert bulk rows. Implemented SCRIPT can be optimize and change according to requirement once requirement is clear.

iv) Test my script.First thoroughly test it from any number between 101 to 921

Just change the value of @input

```
DECLARE @Input INT = 127--change here
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(10) = ''
    ,@TempOutput VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Base INT = 100
    ,@z INT = 26
    ,@Rem INT
DECLARE @Tempinput INT = @Input

WHILE (
        @Tempinput > 0
        AND @input > @Base + @z
        )
BEGIN
    SET @TempOutput = ''

    IF (@Tempinput > @Base)
    BEGIN
        SET @Rem = @Tempinput % @Base
    END

    IF (
            (@Rem % @z) = 0
            AND (@Rem / @z) > 1
            )
    BEGIN
        SET @Tempinput = (@Rem / @z) - 1
        SET @Rem = @Rem % @z

        PRINT '23'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@Rem > @z)
        BEGIN
            SET @Tempinput = @Rem / @z
            SET @Rem = @Rem % @z

            PRINT @Tempinput
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Rem = @Tempinput % @z
            SET @Tempinput = @Tempinput / @z
        END
    END

    IF (
            @Rem > 0
            AND @Rem <= @z
            )
        SET @TempOutput = CHAR(@Rem + 64)
    ELSE IF (@Rem = 0)
        SET @TempOutput = 'Z'
    SET @Output = @TempOutput + @Output
END

IF (@input <= @Base + @z)
    SET @Output = CHAR((@input % @Base) + 64)

SELECT cast(@Input AS VARCHAR(10)) + @Output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always convert numeric value into alphabatical form, so you should store numeric value (101) and convert it to 101A when needed with function like `fn_NumericToAlphabatical` (you should write this function yourself using loops and `CHAR` function)

You should generate numeric value with sequences

You can create computed persistent column to improve perfomance